# Replace spring bean in one context with mock version from another context

Tags: spring, testing, mocking, javabeans, context.xml

I'm writing an integration test where an application context xml is initialized during startup. There are several test methods in the test class which make use of a specific bean 'X'(already defined in the xml). My actual requirement is to mock bean X only for one of the test methods.

Inside a test method: I tried creating a separate application context using ClassPathXMLApplicationContext with only the mock bean 'M'.

Now I have two Application Contexts (AC): 
1. One created during test case startup (which contains the actual bean X) and 
2. One created using ClassPathXMLApplicationContext within the test method (which has the mock bean M).

I want to replaced the actual bean definition 'X' within AC:1, using the mock bean definition 'M' from AC:2.

Can somebody throw some light on this please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is not a clear way to replace a a bean in a refreshed `ApplicationContext` unless you close it and refresh it again.

To emulate it, the common approach is to use a `Proxy` of the bean that you want to replace  and change the target at runtime.

You can do it easily using the framework aop support classes:

```
<bean id="realBean" class="RealClass" />
<bean id="mockBean" class="MockClass" />
<bean id="targetSource" class="org.springframework.aop.target.HotSwappableTargetSource">
    <constructor-arg ref="realBean" />
</bean>

<bean id="bean" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetSource" ref="targetSource" />
</bean>
```

```
@Test
public void testWithMockBean() {
Object real = targetSource.swap(mock);
....
// do your test work
...
targetSource.swap(real);

}
```

Comment: I tried this out in a small example.  The gist is here: https://gist.github.com/harschware/111416de4c8fe53689b8c5ca15140a67

Answer (score 23):

You can :

- use the [Profile](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) annotation if you have spring 3.1.
- use the [Primary](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) annotation
- use [qualifiers](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-filtering-components-in-auto-scanning/)
- wire the bean yourself in the spring context

and i'm sure there are even more options.

Comment: **@Primary** is the best answer: "Indicates that a bean should be given preference when multiple candidates are qualified to autowire (...)"

Comment: For me \@Primary is also the best Answer, but what happen when when \@Qualifier is used?

Comment: Really liked the @Primary suggestion. This is very helpful in special test scenarios...

Answer (score 3):

Create a testApplicationContext with

```
<beans>
    <import resource="classpath*:appContext.xml" />
    <bean id="mockbeanOfX" class=....../>
</beans>
```

and then load this test application context in your testcase. Now you can get the mock bean from the application context and pass it whereever needed.