# Can programatically created object can access spring context via annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Let's say I have following spring.xml (SomeBean is managed by spring)

```
<bean id="some_bean" class="SomeBean" />
```

and class (this one is not managed)

```
public class MyClass {
    @<some magic or something else?>
    private SomeBean sb;
}
```

and my main

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyClass().getSB();
    }
}
```

How to make that by creation of new class (using new keyword) MyClass instance have access to bean with id="some_bean"?

Comment: Look into AspectJ. It's otherwise impossible if you don't have access to the ApplicationContext.

Comment: You have to make MyClass available to Spring. But you can set it at runtime: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328904/dynamically-declare-beans-at-runtime-in-spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject `some_bean` directly to your pre-existing `MyClass` if you employ Spring AOP and annotate it with [`@Configurable`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch07s08.html):

```
@Configurable
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    private SomeBean sb;
}
```

The above code will inject by Type. If you happen to have more than one `SomeBean`s, then inject by name:

```
@Configurable
public class MyClass {
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("some_bean")
        private SomeBean sb;
    }
```

Comment: Well I tried that. But nothings happen (except NPE). I try dig a little bit to find maybe some configuration, but not find anything what would be useful for some using `AspectJ` for 1st time. It says that I might need 3 jars (`aspectjrt`, `aspectjtools` and `aspectjweaver`) so i add them into dependency. Also tried add something like `<context:spring-configured/>` but nothing really happens as well. What I'm missing?

Comment: Ok. I manage to solve it using -javaagent:path_to_agent.jar at load time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to application context then you can get it as:

```
    public class MyClass {
        @Autowire
        private SomeBean sb;
    }

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBeanProperties(myClass, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE, true);
    }
```

Comment: Quite ugly way, AspectJ one looks nice, but if I wouldn't manage to set that thing up I probably do it that way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative if you don't like AOP / AspectJ is to create a `MyClassFactory` bean that is responsible for creating new instances of `MyClass`, and inject a `SomeBean` reference into them (either by constructor injection or method injection), e.g.

```
@Service
public class MyClassFactory {
    @Autowired
    private SomeBean sb;

    public MyClass createMyClassWithSomeBean() {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.setSomeBean(sb);
        return myClass;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        MyClassFactory factory = ctx.getBean(MyClassFactory.class);
        MyClass myClass = factory.createMyClassWithSomeBean();
    }
}
```