# Spring 4 Create Bean Programmatically

Tags: spring-4

I've been looking for a way to add datasources at runtime. I want to move away from defining the datasources in @Configuration class and instead when the app loads i want to dynamically create the datasource beans and inject them into the Spring context. I'm not really sure how I can go about doing that.

Comment: Did you read this question ? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328904/dynamically-declare-beans-at-runtime-in-spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328904/dynamically-declare-beans-at-runtime-in-spring)

Comment: I did, and I also seen other examples as well. I started using spring when it was Spring 4.x, i'm looking for the new way or the best practice way.

Comment: I posted an answer, let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with, not sure if this is the right approach or not, if there is a better way please share.

```
    @Component
class SpringContextListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource ds = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://MySQL:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&maxAllowedPacket=512000");
        ds.setUsername("MYUSERNAME");
        ds.setPassword("MYPASSWORD");
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = (ConfigurableApplicationContext) event.getApplicationContext();
        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory bf = ctx.getBeanFactory();
        bf.registerSingleton("mysqlDSN", ds);
    };
}
```

This is an example of what I want to do, but I would like to eventually have the ability to dynamically create beans and add them to them to spring rather than writing out config files.