# Create queue runtime in Grails with RabbitMQ plugin

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a system where external systems can subscribe to events generated by my system. The system is written in Grails 2, using the [RabbitMQ plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/rabbitmq) for internal messaging. The events to external systems are communicated via HTTP.

I would like to create a queue for each subscriber to prevent that a slow subscriber endpoint slows down messages to an other subscriber. Subscriptions can occur runtime, that's why defining the queues in the application config is not desirable.

How can I create a queue with a topic binding runtime with the Grails RabbitMQ plugin?

As reading messages from RabbitMQ queues is directly coupled to services, a side-problem to creating the queue runtime could be to have multiple instances of that Grails service. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Spring AMQP which is used by the Grails RabbitMQ plugin. Removed some methods/arguments as they are not relevant to the sample:

```
class MyUpdater {
  void handleMessage(Object message) {
    String content = new String(message)

    // do whatever you need with the message
  }
}


import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue
import org.springframework.amqp.core.TopicExchange
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory

class ListenerInitiator {

  // autowired
  ConnectionFactory   rabbitMQConnectionFactory

  protected void initiateListener() {
    RabbitAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(rabbitMQConnectionFactory)

    // normally passed to this method, moved to local vars for simplicity
    String queueName = "myQueueName"
    String routingKey = "#"
    String exchange = "myExchange"

    Queue queue = new Queue(queueName)
    admin.declareQueue(queue)
    TopicExchange exchange = new TopicExchange(exchange)
    admin.declareExchange(exchange)

    admin.declareBinding( BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(routingKey) )

    // normally passed to this method, moved to local var for simplicity
    MyUpdater listener = new MyUpdater()
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container =
        new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(rabbitMQConnectionFactory)
    MessageListenerAdapter adapter = new MessageListenerAdapter(listener)
    adapter.setMessageConverter(new SimpleMessageConverter())

    container.setMessageListener(adapter)
    container.setQueueNames(queueName)
    container.start()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a ready solution for You but if you follow the code in the [RabbitmqGrailsPlugin Descriptor](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-rabbitmq/blob/master/src/main/groovy/grails.plugins.rabbitmq/RabbitmqGrailsPlugin.groovy#L61-L206) especially the `doWithSpring` section
You should be able to recreate the steps necessary to initialize a new `Queue` and associated `Listener` dynamically at runtime.

It all comes down then to pass the needed parameters, register necessary spring beans and start the listeners.

To answer your second question I think you can come up with some naming convention and create a new queue handler for each queue. An example how to create spring beans dynamically can be found here: [dynamically declare beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328904/dynamically-declare-beans-at-runtime-in-spring)

Just a short example how I would quickly register a Queue it requires much more wiring etc...

```
def createQ(queueName) {
    def queuesConfig = {
        "${queueName}"(durable: true, autoDelete: false,)
    }
    def queueBuilder = new RabbitQueueBuilder()
    queuesConfig.delegate = queueBuilder
    queuesConfig.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    queuesConfig()

    queueBuilder.queues?.each { queue ->
        if (log.debugEnabled) {
            log.debug "Registering queue '${queue.name}'"
        }
        BeanDefinitionBuilder builder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(Queue.class);
        builder.addConstructorArgValue(queue.name)
        builder.addConstructorArgValue(Boolean.valueOf(queue.durable))
        builder.addConstructorArgValue(Boolean.valueOf(queue.exclusive))
        builder.addConstructorArgValue(Boolean.valueOf(queue.autoDelete))
        builder.addConstructorArgValue(queue.arguments)
        DefaultListableBeanFactory factory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) grailsApplication.mainContext.getBeanFactory();
        factory.registerBeanDefinition("grails.rabbit.queue.${queue.name}", builder.getBeanDefinition());
    }
}
```