# How to add bean programmatically to Spring context?

Tags: java, spring

I would like to create custom child context from some configuration and additionally add some beans to it programmatically.

I read answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4540762/258483 about `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` but don't understand how to use it. If I write implementation of `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` then what to do with it next? Add to context? But this is the question: how to add bean to context! If I would be able to add `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` to context, then why I would ask how to add beans?

The problem is that I have context and want to add bean to it.

I know I can instantiate beans and autowire them with

```
Context#getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().createBean(klass);
```

but this apparently just wires class, but not adds it to context?

Comment: You basically have to add the bean to the context you get when creating a new Spring context, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15329777/3858121

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Bean Programmatically to Spring Web App Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540713/add-bean-programmatically-to-spring-web-app-context)

Answer (score 17):

From `Spring 5.0` onwards, you can register your beans dynamically directly using the `GenericApplicationContext`.

```
GenericApplicationContext ac = ....;
// example
ac.registerBean("myspecialBean", Integer.class, () -> new Integer(100));
// using BeanDefinitionCustomizer
ac.registerBean("myLazySpecialBean", Integer.class, () -> new Integer(100), (bd) -> bd.setLazyInit(true));
```

See the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/GenericApplicationContext.html#registerBean-java.lang.Class-org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionCustomizer...-) here for different APIs for `registerBean`

Comment: I am using Spring 5.3 (Spring Boot v2.7.1) and `registerBean()` is unknown to `ApplicationContext`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Originally answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49777194/5452132) by myself, repeating it here as well.

> Actually `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` derived from `AbstractApplicationContext`, which has empty `postProcessBeanFactory` method left for override

```
/**
 * Modify the application context's internal bean factory after its standard
 * initialization. All bean definitions will have been loaded, but no beans
 * will have been instantiated yet. This allows for registering special
 * BeanPostProcessors etc in certain ApplicationContext implementations.
 * @param beanFactory the bean factory used by the application context
 */
protected void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
}
```

To leverage this, Create `AnnotationConfigApplicationContextProvider` class which may look like following(given for `Vertx` instance example, you can use `MyClass` instead)...

```
public class CustomAnnotationApplicationContextProvider {
private final Vertx vertx;

public CustomAnnotationApplicationContextProvider(Vertx vertx) {
    this.vertx = vertx;
}

/**
 * Register all beans to spring bean factory
 *
 * @param beanFactory, spring bean factory to register your instances
 */
private void configureBeans(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
    beanFactory.registerSingleton("vertx", vertx);
}

/**
 * Proxy method to create {@link AnnotationConfigApplicationContext} instance with no params
 *
 * @return {@link AnnotationConfigApplicationContext} instance
 */
public AnnotationConfigApplicationContext get() {
    return new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext() {

        @Override
        protected void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
            super.postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);
            configureBeans(beanFactory);
        }
    };
}

/**
 * Proxy method to call {@link AnnotationConfigApplicationContext#AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DefaultListableBeanFactory)} with our logic
 *
 * @param beanFactory bean factory for spring
 * @return
 * @see AnnotationConfigApplicationContext#AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DefaultListableBeanFactory)
 */
public AnnotationConfigApplicationContext get(DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
    return new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(beanFactory) {

        @Override
        protected void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
            super.postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);
            configureBeans(beanFactory);
        }
    };
}

/**
 * Proxy method to call {@link AnnotationConfigApplicationContext#AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Class[])} with our logic
 *
 * @param annotatedClasses, set of annotated classes for spring
 * @return
 * @see AnnotationConfigApplicationContext#AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Class[])
 */
public AnnotationConfigApplicationContext get(Class<?>... annotatedClasses) {
    return new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(annotatedClasses) {

        @Override
        protected void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
            super.postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);
            configureBeans(beanFactory);
        }
    };
}

/**
 * proxy method to call {@link AnnotationConfigApplicationContext#AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(String...)} with our logic
 *
 * @param basePackages set of base packages for spring
 * @return
 * @see AnnotationConfigApplicationContext#AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(String...)
 */
public AnnotationConfigApplicationContext get(String... basePackages) {
    return new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(basePackages) {

        @Override
        protected void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
            super.postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);
            configureBeans(beanFactory);
        }
    };
}
}
```

While creating `ApplicationContext` you can create it using

```
Vertx vertx = ...; // either create or for vertx, it'll be passed to main verticle
ApplicationContext context = new CustomAnnotationApplicationContextProvider(vertx).get(ApplicationSpringConfig.class);
```

Comment: Please don't repeat yourself. Mark the question as duplicate instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this in my current application, because I already have an object that I want to register.
I can have `applicationContext` injected as a bean.

```
private void registerAsBean(
  ApplicationContext injectedApplicationContext, 
  MyClass objectToRegisterAsBean, 
  String beanName) {

    AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = 
      injectedApplicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    beanFactory.initializeBean(objectToRegisterAsBean, beanName);
}
```