# Use registerBean() to register multiple beans of same type

Tags: java, spring

I'm reading Spring Start Here (screenshot attached). The author says it's possible to add multiple beans of the same type to the context using context.registerBean(). I tried adding two Parrots to the context using the following code. The print statements are there to verify that there are two calls of context.registerBean(). Initially, I tried adding the beans like so and still only one Parrot was added.

```
for (Parrot p : parrots) {
        context.registerBean(Parrot.class, parrotSupplier);
    }
```

I'm confused by the results of running this code, as only one bean is registered.
**How can I add multiple beans of the same type using AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.registerBean()?**

Results of running main

```
Kiki
Kiki
Iteration!
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor
org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory
org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor
parrot
projectConfig
```

Main class

```
package main;

import config.ProjectConfig;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        var context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ProjectConfig.class);

        Parrot x = new Parrot();
        x.setName("Kiki");

        Parrot y = new Parrot();
        y.setName("Kiki");

        Parrot[] parrots = new Parrot[]{x,y};

        Iterator<Parrot> parrotIterator = Arrays.asList(parrots).iterator();

        Supplier<Parrot> parrotSupplier = () -> {
        if (parrotIterator.hasNext()) System.out.println("Iteration!");
        return parrotIterator.next();
    };

        for (Parrot p : parrots) {
            System.out.println(p.getName());
            context.registerBean(Parrot.class, parrotSupplier);
        }

        Parrot p = context.getBean(Parrot.class);
        Arrays.asList(context.getBeanDefinitionNames()).stream().sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Parrot class

```
public class Parrot {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

ProjectConfig class

```
public class ProjectConfig {
}
```

[page 56 of Spring Start Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XClBK.png)

Comment: From the sample code - the parrot supplier only returns the "x" instance of the Parrot. Also, this other post might also be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49930149/5818270

Comment: thank you for pointing out my mistake Tim! I used an iterator and it still doesn't work. I checked the link you provided but I don't see how this code stub explains adding multiple beans of the same type

Comment: My guess that Spring is not willing to register two beans with exactly the same coordinates; that is, with the same type and name.  If a name is not specified, it is created from the type.  Since you're registering the same type twice without explicit names, and therefore with the same name twice as well, Spring is considering that bean already registered.  Ask yourself this...if there's no way for Spring to distinguish between to registered beans, what use can there be to register both of them?  How would Spring ever know to choose between them?

Comment: good point. I don't know how to set the name without using @Bean(name=<name>). ..does this mean there isn't a way to add multiple beans of the same type using .registerBean()?

Comment: I just tried this.  There's an overload of `registerBean` that's just like the one you're using but that takes a name as a first parameter. I created a test that did what you're doing.  Spring throws an exception saying "A bean with that name has already been defined and overriding is disabled.".  If I add a constant name parameter to `resisterBean` as an additional (first) parameter, I get the same error.  But if I supply two different names each time I call `registerBean`, everything works as expected with no errors.  I didn't check, but I expect that Spring has  registered both beans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't register two beans with the same name and the same type, because then there's no way for Spring to distinguish between them.  How would Spring ever know, for example, which one to inject in a particular situation?  You can qualify injections of a particular type by the bean name, but only if beans of the same type have different names.

If you don't supply a name, Spring computes one from the type of the object.  So in your case, you're attempting to register two beans with both the same type and the same name.

I ran your example, and for me it doesn't even run.  I get an error:

```
A bean with that name has already been defined and overriding is disabled.
```

There's an overload of `registerBean` that takes the same two params as the one you're calling, but takes a third name parameter.  I changed your code slightly to use this version and to pass two different names:

```
boolean first = true;
for (Parrot p : parrots) {
    System.out.println(p.getName());
    context.registerBean(first? "first" : "second", Parrot.class, parrotSupplier);
    first = false;
}
```

This version of the code works without throwing an error.  I assume that since it refused to do so before, it is now registering both beans.

UPDATE: Reading that error message again, I wondered if maybe you can't register two beans with the same name even if they have different types. It turns out that this is true.  Every Spring bean has to have a unique name.  Since the name is computed from the type of the object if not specified, you can register one bean of any particular type without specifying a name.

Comment: ah thank you!! I had originally tried something similar using this overload (with the name parameter as the first argument) but I kept getting an NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException. Turns out, that exception didn't come from .registerBean() but from having >1 Parrot bean and calling  context.getBean(Parrot.class). Thank you for helping me realize that spring requires unique bean names.