# Spring Boot using application property in Service annotation name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I would like to do something like that following

```
@Service("${application.property}")
public class SampleClass {
```

similar to how we see for Value annotation

```
@Value("${application.property}") 
private String field;
```

The "${application.property}" would be taken from the application.properties file. I feel like this should be possible as the application.properties file is in memory. I have searched however and cannot find a solution. Maybe there is some secret annotation or other configuration to achieve this? Any help is appreciated

Comment: I would suggest to explain what do you want to achieve by specifying the bean name via property.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328904/dynamically-declare-beans-at-runtime-in-spring 
TL;DR you cannot do it via annotations, but you could do it programatically